# spring returning map top ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to return a map from my spring controller to ajax call.
its working fine, but i am getting the response in a string.
how to get the values from ajax response??
my code...

In Controller..

```
> Map<String, Object> uploadFile(MultipartHttpServletRequest request,
> @RequestParam String projectCode, HttpServletResponse response,
> FileUploadJQ fujq, UserMaster um) {
>         ..............
>         ..............
>         fileUploadJQRepo.save(fujq);
>         System.out.println("ID::" + fujq.getFileId());
>         long fileId = fileUploadJQRepo.findByFileNameAndCreatedDate(fujq.getFileName(),
> fujq.getCreatedDate()).getFileId();
>         Map<String, Object> returnVal = new HashMap<String, Object>();
>         returnVal.put("upFileId", fileId);
>         returnVal.put("url", "<a href='/fileD/fileId/" + fileId + "'>" + fujq.getFileName() + "</a>");
>         return returnVal;
```

ajax...

```
success: function(data) {
                var percentVal = '100%';
                bar.width(percentVal)
                percent.html(percentVal);
                var d="["+data+"]";
                    <c:forEach items="d" var="sa" varStatus="idx">
                            alert(${idx.index})
                    </c:forEach> 
                $('#result').html(data);
            },
```

in browser i can see the data as...

> `"{"upFileId":97,"url":"<a href='/fileD/fileId/97'>manifest.json</a>"}"`

so how to get the value against `upFileId` and `url` ??

Plz help...

Thank you.

Comment: i tried 'c:foreach'  tag... but not working...

Comment: You'll need to try your question again with some formatted code. Please include the method declaration in your controller.

Comment: @kungfuters   I did that..